# calling pre-installed client COM+ in pure javascript

Tags: asp-classic, com+

Is there a way from javascript to call a client **"pre-installed" COM+ (component)**??

Let say, I have "printclass.dll" already installed in every client PC (and registered properly on my COM+), and I am using classic ASP accessing from a webserver. What I wanted to do is that when I print, I wanted to call a client COMponent printing program instead the server-side.

example;

```
<input title="Print report" type="button" value="Print Invoice" onclick="javascript:reportNow(2301)">
```

and under javascript;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function reportNow(invNo) {
  //
  // call the client COM+ here, printclass.dll
  // var myobj = "printclass.dll"
  // myobj.PrintInvoice(invNo)
 }
</script>
```

*I want it in IE browser only*. My problem really is the "client" printing-side of my classic ASP pages. I am using client ActiveX (ocx) BUT the problem is that IE11 doesn't permit ActiveX anymore... so my browser-based application is limited to IE8 to IE10.

Comment: I suspect the answer is probably no.  COM and ActiveX are different names for the same thing, COM seems to be used in the context of server side code and ActiveX in the context of client side code.

Comment: I suspect that you're having an x/y problem: you're asking about complicated COM vs. ActiveX stuff, but what are you actually trying to achieve? User hits a "print" button: now what's supposed to happen?

Comment: @Martha; I am using IE for printing "selected" elements/fields within the ASP page and it is working well using ActiveX. What I'm after is that IE removed the use of ActiveX already starting with their IE11 (and eventually MSEdge).

So my supposed to be solution is "pre-installed" COM+ on the client, and to be executed by Javascript. So that's actually my point in creating such query.

Question is: is there any other means that we could print "selected" field element within the page not using the @media print?

Comment: @John; yes I think so. It seems that since I'm using "pre-installed component" (configured directly thru COM+), it is still considered as server-side... and yes, it is not an ActiveX. 

I am printing selected fields on my page - to a blank preprinted "Sales Invoice", positioning the selected fields to specific coordinates on the sales invoice. If ActiveX is to be removed, what is their solutions in printing then?